# PyTorch alternative for tf.data.experimental.sample_from_datasets

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch

Suppose I have two datasets, dataset one with 100 items and dataset two with 5000 items.

Now I want that during training my model sees as much items from dataset one as from dataset two.

In Tensorflow I can do:

```
dataset = tf.data.experimental.sample_from_datasets(
    [dataset_one, dataset_two], weights=[50,1], seed=None
)
```

Is there an alternative in PyTorch that does the same?

I think this is not too difficult to implement by creating a custom dataset (not working example)

```
from torch.utils.data import Dataset

class SampleDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, datasets, weights):
        self.datasets = datasets
        self.weights = weights

    def __len__(self):
        return sum([len(dataset) for dataset in self.datasets])

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        # sample a random number and based on that sample an item
        
        return self.datasets[dataset_idx][sample_idx]
```

However, this seems quite common. Is there already something like this available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a direct equivalent in PyTorch.

However, there's a function called [`torch.utils.data.WeightedRandomSampler`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.WeightedRandomSampler) which samples indices based on a list of probabilities. You can use this in combination with [`torch.data.utils.ConcatDataset`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.ConcatDataset) and [`torch.utils.data.DataLoader`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.DataLoader)'s `sampler` option.

I'll give an example with two datasets: `SetA` has *500* elements and `SetB` which only has *10*.

First, you can create a concatenation of all your datasets with `ConcaDataset`:

```
ds = ConcatDataset([SetA(), SetB()])
```

Then, we need to sample it. The problem is, you can't just give `WeightedRandomSampler` `[50, 1]`, as you did in Tensorflow. As a workaround, you can create a list of probabilities of the same length as the size of the total dataset.

The corresponding probability list for this example would be:

```
dist = np.array([1/51]*500 + [50/51]*10)
```

Essentially, the first *500* indices (i.e. indices 'pointing' to `SetA`) will have a probability of *1/51* of being choosen while the following *10* indices (i.e. indices in `SetB`) will have a probability of *50/51* (i.e much more likely to being sampled since there are less elements in `SetB`, this is the desired result!)

We can create a sampler from that distribution:

```
WeightedRandomSampler(dist, 10)
```

Where *10* is the number of sampled elements. I would put the size of the smallest dataset, otherwise you would likely be going over the same datapoints multiple times during the same epoch...

Finally, we just have to instanciate the dataloader with our dataset and sampler:

```
dl = DataLoader(ds, sampler=sampler)
```

To summarize:

```
ds = ConcatDataset([SetA(), SetB()])
dist = np.array([1/51]*500 + [50/51]*10)
sampler = WeightedRandomSampler(dist, 10)
dl = DataLoader(ds, sampler=sampler)
```

---

**Edit**, for any number of datasets:

```
sets = [SetA(), SetB(), SetC()]
ds = ConcatDataset(sets)

dist = np.concatenate([[(len(ds) - len(s))/len(ds)]*len(s) for s in sets])
sampler = WeightedRandomSampler(weights=dist, num_samplesmin([len(s) for s in sets])
dl = DataLoader(ds, sampler=sampler)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think to avoid having datapoints multiple times in one epoch this: replacement=False has to be added to the WeightedRandomSampler

Comment: So then the num_samples in your code for any number of datasets can be min([len(s) for s in sets] * len(sets)